# Batch: „if else“. Whats wrong is this code?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I want if pasw and paswconfirm are not the same that it says 3.

but I this is what I get:

```
Wachtwoord:test
Type het wachtwoord overnieuw:xzcv
1
3
```

---

This is my code:

```
:pasw
cls
:paswretry
set /p pasw=Wachtwoord:
set /p paswconfirm=Type het wachtwoord overnieuw:
if "%pasw%" == "%paswconfirm%" (
  echo Weet je het zeker? Het wachtwoord word: %pasw%
  CHOICE /c YN /n /m (Y/N)
  if "%errorlevel%" == "1" (
    echo 1
    )
  if "%errorlevel%" == "2" (
    echo 2
    )
) else (
  echo 3
  )
```

Comment: You are closing the opened `If` parentheses with the closing `/N)`

Comment: Besides the fact that the closing `)` in `choice /C YN /N /M (Y/N)` closed the `if "%pasw%"=="%paswconfirm%" (` block, which could be avoide by quotation like `choice /C YN /N /M "(Y/N)"`, you need [delaxyed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `ErrorLevel` (so `%ErrorLevel%` becomes `!ErrorLevel!`)...

Comment: I recommend reading answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) to better understand the solutions posted by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) and the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

According to my comment, you are closing the opened `If` parenthesis with the closing `/N)` parenthesss prematurely.

You could therefore just escape that parenthesis with a caret, **`^)`**:

```bat
:paswretry
Set /P "pasw=Wachtwoord: "
Set /P "paswconfirm=Type het wachtwoord overnieuw: "
If "%pasw%"=="%paswconfirm%" (
    Echo Weet je het zeker? Het wachtwoord word: %pasw%
    Choice /C YN /N /M (Y/N^)
    If "%ErrorLevel%"=="1" (
        Echo 1
    ) Else (
        Echo 2
    )
)
```

Or you could doublequote the message text as shown in the examples within the usage information, *(output when entering `Choice /?` at the Command Prompt)*:

```bat
:paswretry
Set /P "pasw=Wachtwoord: "
Set /P "paswconfirm=Type het wachtwoord overnieuw: "
If "%pasw%"=="%paswconfirm%" (
    Echo Weet je het zeker? Het wachtwoord word: %pasw%
    Choice /C YN /N /M "(Y/N)"
    If "%ErrorLevel%"=="1" (
        Echo 1
    ) Else (
        Echo 2
    )
)
```

However the `Choice` command works automatically using `[Y,N]?`, and will therefore need no additional options.

You should use either this:

```bat
:paswretry
Set /P "pasw=Wachtwoord: "
Set /P "paswconfirm=Type het wachtwoord overnieuw: "
If "%pasw%"=="%paswconfirm%" (
    Echo Weet je het zeker? Het wachtwoord word: %pasw%
    Choice
    If ErrorLevel 2 (
        Echo 2
    ) Else (
        Echo 1
    )
)
```

this, *(better)*:

```bat
:paswretry
Set /P "pasw=Wachtwoord: "
Set /P "paswconfirm=Type het wachtwoord overnieuw: "
If Not "%pasw%"=="%paswconfirm%" GoTo paswretry
Echo Weet je het zeker? Het wachtwoord word: %pasw%
Choice
If ErrorLevel 2 (
    Echo 2
) Else (
    Echo 1
)
```

or this, *(even better)*:

```bat
:paswretry
Set /P "pasw=Wachtwoord: "
Set /P "paswconfirm=Type het wachtwoord overnieuw: "
If Not "%pasw%"=="%paswconfirm%" GoTo paswretry
Echo Weet je het zeker? Het wachtwoord word: %pasw%
Choice
Echo %ErrorLevel%
```

In the latter two examples I've used `GoTo paswretry` on line `4`; that of course can be changed to `GoTo SomethingElse`, *(even `:EOF` to exit the script block)*, as required

Comment: If my answer(s) solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted, _by clicking on the large check mark to its left_.